# TBB complains something is wrong if Tor is Listening on 0.0.0.0 (via SocksPort)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, socks

If a SocksListenAddress or SocksPort directive is added to torrc-defaults such that Tor listens for Socks Connections on anything other than 127.0.0.1, TBB will complain on launch that:

> **Something Went Wrong!**
>   Tor is not working in this browser.

Of course, Tor is working. However, I imagine there is a reason for this.

Is it considered unsafe to open the SocksPort to the LAN, or is this a bug that should be filed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At startup, Torbutton compares the SOCKS listener address reported by tor (the same as what you set in your torrc) to what is configured in the browser.  See:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git/blob/818f9b0a076dc31cc87544227aea164b07235276:/src/chrome/content/torbutton.js#l1890

Most likely, the check is failing because 0.0.0.0 != 127.0.0.1.  I think it should be safe to allow connections from any computer on the LAN, so arguably this is a bug in Torbutton.  One workaround would be to use about:config to set the hidden browser preference extensions.torbutton.local_tor_check to false to force a Torbutton to use a remote check "Is Tor working?" instead.

Also, it would be better to modify torrc instead of torrc-defaults (the latter may be overwritten when Tor Browser is updated).

Comment: On the question of a bug, I guess TBB as a whole is designed to warn about any modification, so the logic in torbutton_local_tor_check() is OK.
On torrc/torrc-defaults, I would generally favour a fresh install to an update anyway with Tor Browser.